# Let $x,y$ be two complex numbers. Then what the set of solutions of $x^y=xy$.

Tags: complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

One of my motivations for studying this problem is mathematical curiosity, as I am aware that it has the solution $2$. I am intrigued to determine whether 2 is the sole solution or if there are others.

The equation also exhibits an intriguing pattern:

...$=2$^^^$2=2$^^$2=2^2=2⋅2=2+2=1+1+1+1.$

In my opinion, this equation is worth solving.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $2$ is a solution?  Your equation has two variables.  Note that, unless $x=0$, your equation is equivalent to $x^{y-1}=y$ which, of course, has lots of solutions.

Comment: @lulu $x=y=2$ is solution

Comment: Perhaps the Lambert W function might be helpful?

Comment: But you didn't specify that $x=y$...there are plenty of solutions in which $x\neq y$.  Indeed, other than $x=0$, $x=y^{1/(y-1)}$ gives solutions for any $y\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial answer)

The whole set of solutions might be hard to determine in the present case. By inspection, we can find some of them, such as $x = y = 1$, $x = y = 2$ or $x = 0$ with $y > 0$ for instance. Provided suitable domains for $x$ and $y$, the Lambert W function permits to find a solution curve too, since your equation can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{x} = ye^{-y\ln x}$, hence $y = \frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{-\ln x}$.

Now, given that you are ultimately interested by the fact that $2+2 = 2\cdot2 = 2^2$, you may look at [hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#), because it is known that $H_n(2,2) = 4 \;\,\forall n \ge 1$ actually.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.